# I can't upload multiple images at one time in ASP.net live

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I developed website in `ASP.net` MVC4. User has to upload 2 images of his/her project.

On local host everything is working fine. but when I upload it on my web-hosting server, it doesn't allow me to add project. [Here is the link for the website](http://projecthunk.com/).

When I upload a project, it says that:

> "server encountered an error"

, and the error occurs in controller function.
Here is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult muproject()
    {
        if (Session["uid"] == null)                
            return RedirectToAction("login");
        Project proj = new Project();
        proj.P_Intro = Request["intro"];
        proj.P_Name = Request["name"];
        proj.P_Result = Request["conclu"];
        proj.P_Sol = Request["body"];
        proj.P_Type = Request["type"];
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"]);
        proj.U_Id = id;

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
            string unique = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                string simg = @"~\Files\" + unique + ".jpg";
                proj.U_Path1 = @"/Files/" + unique + ".jpg";
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(simg));
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                string simg = @"~\Files\" + unique + ".jpg";
                proj.U_Path2 = @"/Files/" + unique + ".jpg";
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(simg));
            }
        }
        de.Projects.Add(proj);
        de.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("myproject");
    }
```

Structure of DB is in a single table where I'm trying to save 2 images and project's initial `probleb` /`intro`, `Solution`, `Result` , `Type` , `UserID` (as Foreign key). `U_path1` and `U_path2` are paths for images.

I'm trying it for a week now. Could you kindly tell me whats the error and how to solve it?

Comment: Well, which error occurs?

Comment: On local host it runs without any error. after deploying , it says "server encountered an error"